# Value lookup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

This is my whole sample code:

```
package trouble.something

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object Stack {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("app")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def ExFunc[Int](looku: RDD[(Int, Long)]) {
    val ke = 3
    looku.lookup(ke);
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val pi: RDD[(Int, Long)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 9L), (2, 11L)))
    pi.lookup(3)

    val res = ExFunc[Int](pi)
  }
}
```

When I execute the following line, it executes correctly without any errors and produces output

```
pi.lookup(3)
```

But, when I pass `pi` to a function, and use `lookup` as below, then i get an error

```
val res = ExFunc[Int](pi)
```

Passing `pi` to below function

```
def ExFunc[Int](looku: RDD[(Int, Long)]) {
  val ke = 3
  looku.lookup(ke);
}
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Error:(27, 11) value lookup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Long)]
    looku.lookup(ke);
```

Can anybody help me correcting this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function shouldn't be generic. Just remove type parameter

```
def ExFunc(looku: RDD[(Int, Long)]) {
  val ke = 3
  looku.lookup(ke);
}
```

To create generic function provide `ClassTag`, for example

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def ExFunc[T : ClassTag](looku: RDD[(T, Long)], ke: T) {
  looku.lookup(ke);
}
```

Comment: Quite recently seen something similar but the answer was to have `ExFunc` return a function of two parameter groups for `RDD`  and `ke` separately. What do you think about the approach?